# React-admin Searchable multi select fetching from database(other table)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, admin-on-rest, react-admin

I am using `react-admin` for my application. I want to create a searchable(suggesting with possible values) multi-select field input which fetches data(feature name in my case from table features) which can be selected from a table at the backend. My current code looks like this: 
`

```
    export default class ModelCreate extends React.Component<any, any> {
        return (
                    <Create title="Create a Model" {...this.props}>
                        <SimpleForm className="model-container" toolbar={<ModelCreateToolbar />}>

                            <SelectInput
                                source="group"
                                label="Group"
                                choices={GROUP}
                                optionText="name"
                                optionValue="group"
                                style={styles}
                                validate={validateField}
                                required
                            />
                            <ReferenceArrayInput source="id" reference="features">
                                   <SelectArrayInput source="name" reference="features" label="feature" required />
                            </ReferenceArrayInput>
                        </SimpleForm>
                   </Create>
            );
        }
    }
```

`

In this code `feature` is my table name which has entries of id and name.

P.S: I'm using `typescript`.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like the [`AutocompleteInput`](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Inputs.html#autocompleteinput) we had in `admini-on-rest`?

If yes, we chose to remove it from the core as the `Autocomplete` is not provided by material-ui v1 anymore. This means you'll have to implement your own using something like [material-ui-chip-input](https://github.com/TeamWertarbyte/material-ui-chip-input) and [`downshift`](https://github.com/paypal/downshift).

I know someone is working on a react-admin addon for this input. No ETA yet though

Comment: Thanks will try this

Comment: it's 2022 is there any progress in this topic?

Comment: Yes, we provide an AutocompleteArrayInput for this purpose.